# how to format json body sent from axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios

React beginner here and I am using axios to send the body from my form in my frontend. I did a `console.log` on the server side and this is what I see in the `request.body`.

```
req.body {
  '{"body":"{\\"firstName\\":\\"daf\\",\\"lastName\\":\\"afa\\",\\"address\\":\\"af\\",\\"phoneNumber\\":\\"123-933-6177\\",\\"email\\":\\"asfa\\",\\"facilityName\\":\\"afs\\",\\"isSeller\\":false}"}': ''
}
```

class where I print the bad String above

```
checkIfDuplicateEmailAndFacilityNameOnSignUp = (req, res, next) => {
    // get the customer name
    console.log("request", req.body.firstName);
    const updatedBody = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log(updatedBody);
    Customer.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    }).then(customerEmail => {
        if (customerEmail) {
            res.status(400).send({
                message: "This email is already in use"
            });

            return;
        }

        Customer.findOne({
            where: {
                facilityName: req.body.facilityName
            }
        }).then(facilityname => {
            if (facilityname) {
                res.status(400).send({
                    message: "Facility exists already exists"
                });
                return;
            }

            next();
        });
    });
};
```

This is my function to post from the front end

```
  const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

  const formBody = {
    ...this.state,
  };

  axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    data: {
      body: formBody,
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log("response", response);
    console.log("response data", response.data);
  });

  console.log("form submission done");
};
```

state object

```
  state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    address: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    email: "",
    facilityName: "",
    isSeller: false,
  };
```

this is my node server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "*",
    })
);
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);

require('./app/routes/authRoutes')(app);
require('./app/routes/customerRoutes')(app);

const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Now listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

db.sequelize.sync({
    force: true
})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Dropping and Resync DB");
        initial();
    });

// creates roles in database for us
function initial() {
    Role.create({
        id: 1,
        roleType: "buyer"
    });

    Role.create({
        id: 2,
        roleType: "seller"
    });
};
```

I tried using JSON.parse() but I get an exception with the message `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`. Any idea on how I can go about parsing this?

Update 1:

After changing per @Bravo answer the body looks like this now

```
  body: {
    firstName: 'safds',
    lastName: 'asf',
    address: 'adfs',
    phoneNumber: '404-932-6177',
    email: 'asdf',
    facilityName: 'afs',
    isSeller: false
  }
```

Might be a silly question but how do I access the fields. I tried doing body.firstName or body[0] but I get undefined returned?

Comment: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` ... classic case of trying to pass the **string** `[object Object]` .. something somewhere is coercing an object to become a string - it's too bad you don't show where "I tried using JSON.parse"

Comment: updating now @Bravo

Comment: you need to send the data: as a "query string" for `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> headers: {
>     "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
> },
> ```

This is the problem. You're lying about the encoding so Express is running your body through `bodyParser.urlencoded` instead of `bodyParser.json`.

Take the custom headers out and just use Axios' defaults.

Comment: @Bravo — Yes (since it encodes an object passed to the body as JSON, it does the right thing with the Content-Type header).

Comment: Yeah, there's no options handler, but that's another problem, and one that is covered in the cors module's manual.

Comment: @Bravo  — They do, but it isn't set up for preflighted requests.

Comment: What's the bet they added that header to fix the pre-flight issue

Comment: hey @Bravo could you look at the update please.

Comment: `body.firstName` should work fine … but if you have a new question, then ask a *new* question. Don't edit it onto the end of an existing question.

Comment: since the request is using `data:{body:formBody}}`, the `req.body` would have an object called `body` ... so `req.body.body.firstName` - really only need to send `data: formBody` - then it'd be `req.body.firstName`

Comment: Your amazing Bravo hope to be as smart and great of a dev like you :)

Comment: Thank you @Quentin also for your answer!